# Excel 2007 - Adding line breaks in a cell and no line over 50 characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have notes stored in an Excel cell. I add line breaks and dates every time I add a new note.

I need to copy this to another program, but it has a line limit of 50 characters. I want a line break for each new date and for when each date's comment goes over 50 characters.

I'm able to do one or the other, but I can't figure out how to do both. I'd prefer words not to be split up, but at this point I don't care.

Below is some sample input. If needed for a `=SUBSTITUTE` or `=REPLACE` function, I could add a `~` before each date in my input as a delimiter.

Sample Input:

```
07/03 - FU on query. Copies and history included. CC to Jane Doe and John Public  
06/29 - Cust claiming not to have these and wrong PO on query form. Responded with inv  sent dates and locations, correct PO values, and copies.  
06/27 - New ticket opened using query form  
06/12 - Opened ticket with helpdesk asking status  
05/21 - Copy submitted to customeremail@customer.com  
05/14 - Copy sent to John Public and email@customer.com
```

Ideal Output:

```
07/03 - FU on query. Copies and history included.  
CC to Jane Doe and John Public  
06/29 - Cust claiming not to have these and wrong  
PO on query form. Responded with inv sent dates an  
d locations, correct PO values, and copies.  
06/27 - New ticket opened using query form  
06/12 - Opened ticket with helpdesk asking status  
05/21 - Copy submitted to customeremail@customer.c  
om  
05/14 - Copy sent to John Public and email@custome  
r.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something you can use to put 50 char increments into a collection object with which you can either write out to another worksheet or write out to a csv or whatever. Jsut iterate over it and do what you want with the contents

Function to get 50 or less characters worth of words

```
Private Function FindFirst50ishChars(contents As String) As String
    Dim charSum As Integer, splitContents() As String, j As Integer
            Dim returnString As String: returnString = ""
        splitContents = Split(contents, " ")
        charSum = 0
            If Len(contents) <= 50 Then
                returnString = contents
            Else
                For j = LBound(splitContents) To UBound(splitContents)

                    If charSum + Len(splitContents(j)) >= 50 Then
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        returnString = returnString & " " & splitContents(j)
                        charSum = charSum + Len(splitContents(j)) + 1 '+1 for the extra space added
                        Debug.Print Len(returnString)
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        FindFirst50ishChars = Trim(returnString)
End Function
```

Function to Move through your whole range of cells. Call this function and it will return the collection of ~50 char lines

```
Function GetLinesIn50CharIncrements(StartRow As Integer, EndRow As Integer, Column As Integer) As Collection

    Dim row As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim aWs As Worksheet, contents As String
    Dim WholeLineConsumed As Boolean
    Set aWs = ActiveSheet
    Dim linesCollection As Collection: Set linesCollection = New Collection

    For row = StartRow To EndRow
        contents = aWs.Cells(row, Column)
        WholeLineConsumed = False
        Do While Not WholeLineConsumed
            Dim first50 As String
            first50 = FindFirst50ishChars(contents)
            linesCollection.Add first50
            contents = Right(contents, Len(Trim(contents)) - Len(first50))
            If contents = "" Then WholeLineConsumed = True
        Loop
    Next row
    Set GetLinesIn50CharIncrements = linesCollection
End Function
```

**Edit:**

You can make use of this with the following few lines. The `FileSystemObject` requires you add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject: Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Dim FiftyCharLines As Collection: Set FiftyCharLines = GetLinesIn50CharIncrements(1, 6, 1)
Dim i As Integer, f As TextStream
Dim fileName As String: 'fileName = "some fully qualified file path"
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(fileName, ForWriting, True)


For i = 1 To FiftyCharLines.Count
    f.WriteLine FiftyCharLines(i)
Next i
f.Close
```